# Trouble finding suitable optaplanner domain model

Tags: java, optimization, drools, optaplanner

I would like to solve a 2D geometrical optimization problem using optaplanner: Given a function f(x, y) find its global minimum (x, y).

I have trouble finding a suitable domain model:

- The function f can be considered a problem fact. It does not change during planning and is required to calculate the score
- The point (x, y) is represented by the @PlanningEntity class Point with the planning variables x and y
- How can I model the @PlanningSolution class?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one point? Create a FooSolution with a getPointList() that only returns one point.

That being said, I am not sure if OptaPlanner is the best tool for the job for this, but it would make an interesting experiment to try it out.